# Netflix Zuul in Cloud Foundry

Tags: spring-cloud, netflix-zuul, spring-cloud-netflix, cloud-foundry

I am exploring options to have Netflix Zuul as API Gateway for my Microservices in Cloud Foundry. I am not able to see Zuul option in CF marketplace (I see Apigee integration with CF Service Broker API). I wanted to use Netflix Zuul as API Gateway, If I spin up Zuul as regular application it goes behind HA Proxy/Go Router, I think that is not right thing to do. May be I should implement Service Broker API and create Zuul as a service in CF marketplace. Can someone please through some light on this.I it involved task to make Netfliz Zuul as a Service Broker in CF? I see Eureka in Market place but not Zuul. Dont know why it is like this.. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

That will be very helpful if you can come up with zuul managed service in PCF.

Currently what we do is we use spring boot + spring cloud application to develop api gateway. We have to use `spring-cloud-starter-zuul` dependency. Then ahead we need to register gateway app with **Netflix Eureka service registry**.

Lastly we refer registered Zuul api gateway in all our client api applications.

Good luck with cf marketplace Zuul managed service :)

Comment: Hi Pramod, did you deploy Netflix Zuul Spring boot app as a route-service in PCF (User-Provided Service)? or as a regular app? Because if you deploy Zuul as a regular App, it goes behind HA Proxy/Go Router. Can you please let me know if you have deployed Zuul as a User-Provided Service? Thank you.